# Is it possible to get week number automatically from datepicker based on user input in Flask form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm totally new in Flask and I really have no idea how to pass only the week number from user input [datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LX5I.png) (year-month-day) into  `date = request.form.get ("week_number"))`.
I've spent hours looking for a solution, and I doubt if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your HTML form input type, but if you have other form input types, just play around with the `strptime` part of this code using the link I attached below, and tune it to your specification

```html
<input name="week_number" type="datetime-local">
```

You can try stripping the date from the request, like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_input = request.values.get("week_number", default=None)
if date_input is not None and date_input != "":
  week_number = datetime.strptime(date_input, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M").isocalendar()[1]
```

Here is a brief explanation of how to use `datetime.strptime` documentation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-strptime-function/

ISO calendar all it does is convert the `datetime` object to ISO Year, ISO Week Number, and ISO Weekday. [1] allows you to get only the week.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the trick with strptime and isocalendar works :)

Comment: @Angelika I corrected my answer and added some comments to guide you further.